# How to get the attribute value after parsing xml file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I have an xml file and when I parse it using the below python code. This is what it prints as the result :

```
columnInfo {'class': 'com.manu.webservices.metadata.ColumnBean', 'columnName': 'Employee', 'schemaName': 'Workers', 'tableName': 'humanResource'}
```

I want to print **humanResource** from tableName.

```
Result Expected:
humanResource
```

what I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print (child.tag, child.attrib)
```

Comment: `child.attrib['tableName']`

Comment: Why is this question tagged "regex" ?